# Multiloginapp (browser) and selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Multiloginapp supports selenium remote driver, but when I try to start browser:

```
mla_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:37001/api/v1/webdriver'
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=mla_url,
                      desired_capabilities={'multiloginapp-profileId': profile_id})
```

It always crashes:

```
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x15\x03\x03\x00\x02\x02\n',))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Lang: python

Answer (score 1):

I've been having a similar error. You need to do a few things to solve it. I did a ton of things, so I don't know which thing or combination of things resolved the error:

1. Add 127.0.0.1 to your ip listens through cmd administrator.

Instructions here: [Can't access 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543443/cant-access-127-0-0-1)

basically open cmd prompt admin and type:

> `netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1`

2. Modify your hosts file and add

> `127.0.0.1    localhost`

to your hosts file. If it is already there with a "#" in front of it, delete the "#". Your PC will require you to do this in administrator.

instructions here: [127.0.0.1 is accessible/working but localhost not accessible/ not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345132/127-0-0-1-is-accessible-working-but-localhost-not-accessible-not-working)

3. Make Sure multilogin app is allowed through your firewall for private and public connections. Do not mess around with other stuff in firewall.
   instructions: type "Control Panel" in search bar and click "System and Security". Then click "Windows Defender Firewall" then click "Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall". Allow multilogin through public and private and click apply.

After that your error should change

from: 'BadStatusLine'

to: "[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

You need to pay for the selenium automation. However, that is how I managed to fix the connection issue. Idk about the firewall thing though I'm still iffy on that. I'm not sure if anything can go through Multilogin app to your PC, so just be careful.

Edit: Realize this is a month late, but someone else might find it useful.