# After executing npm start, localhost:3000/ gives error 431. The ip address version (192.168..1.3:3000, 127.0.0.1:3000) this loads up my app

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, localhost

After executing npm start, localhost:3000/ gives error 431. The ip address versions (192.168.1.3:3000, 127.0.0.1:3000) this loads up my app. No matter what react app I create, `npm start`, `localhost:3000` opens my browser with a `error 431`. Wasn't sure if it was npm or node so i updated them both to the latest release. Still the same issue. I know I can simply CMD Click the `http://192.168.1.3:3000` to open up my app, but the convenience of `localhost:3000` loading helps the process. Help!

Comment: 431 is  Request Header Fields Too Large. Why you get this with the name but not the IP is odd. Therefore likely to be some configuration issue. Try adding some diagnostics (console output) to your node code to show it is processing a request.

Comment: In your browswers devtools there is a network tab, you can right click the request to localhost and choose copy => copy as fetch. Then add that to your question to see what the request looks like. You should also check out your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))

Comment: @HMR I wasn't sure where i could right click. I checked my host file and followed [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345132/127-0-0-1-is-accessible-working-but-localhost-not-accessible-not-working) but still received ```error 431``` after ```npm start```.

Answer (score 0):

Your system might possibly have some configuration issues.
[LOCALHOST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345132/127-0-0-1-is-accessible-working-but-localhost-not-accessible-not-working) This link has some suggestions, Please do try those. Hope it goes on well!!.. **Happy Coding**!!

Comment: Thank you for the link, but after following it, I still receive the ```error 431```. I tried removing ```:::1 localhost``` and replacing it with ```127.0.0.1 localhost``` and vice versa, but but still ```npm start``` still loads up a ```error 431```.