# why nginx configuration doesnt work for all hosts

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx conf under `conf.d/myapp.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:13523;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

This only works when I do `curl -s 127.0.0.1:80/product` but when I do `curl -s localhost:80/product` or `curl -s <machine_ip>:80/product` it doesnt work. I made sure that nginx is running on all interfaces that is `0.0.0.0` so any idea why it doesn't work besides `127.0.0.1` ?

I had tried the following and it still doesn't work

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:13523;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "*doesnt work*" mean, exactly, what is the error? What does your `/etc/hosts` look like? What does `dig localhost` show? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524826/localhost-not-working-in-chrome-127-0-0-1-does-work, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345132/127-0-0-1-is-accessible-working-but-localhost-not-accessible-not-working